# Using blog post tags with JSON

Tags: php, json

I have some JSON as below

```
"tags": 
{
    "business-school": 
     {
        "name": "Business School",
        "slug": "business-school",
        "parent": 0,
        "description": "",
        "post_count": 13,
        "id": 169072,
        "taxonomy": "post_tag"
     },
     "canterbury": 
     {
         "name": "Canterbury",
         "slug": "canterbury",
         "parent": 0,
         "description": "",
         "post_count": 37,
         "id": 5349,
         "taxonomy": "post_tag"
```

I have managed to display the relevant tags that were entered with the posts. On other blogs though I have seen the tags as hyperlinks and was wondering how this was implemented. what would they be linked to?. Is it something that is possible within a JSON framework with PHP bearing in mind I am not that familiar with JSON or is it something that is best left to blogging sites.

Comment: On which other blog you've seen tags as hyperlink. Can you share the link with us?

Comment: If you dont know _what would they be linked to_ then its a fairly acedemic question. First decide what to link them to and then worry about how to link them

Comment: not quite sure what you meant, but if you are able to display the tags, you can just add an anchor to the tags to make them links, e.g. <a href="url">tags</a>.  as to what the links link to, it's up to you to define the urls.

Comment: Here the example, https://blogs.canterbury.ac.uk/cafa/herne-bay-newsreel-1936/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can keep the relationship of your data like below then you can easily implement that TAG with HYPERLINKS technique with your blog post also.

**Format for TAGS Where each Tag will be associated with an ID**

So your anchor link will be like -

`https://blogs.canterbury.ac.uk/cafa/tag/555/`  `https://blogs.canterbury.ac.uk/cafa/tag/777/`

```
"tags":
{
    "business-school":
     {
        "name": "Business School",
        "slug": "business-school",
        "parent": 0,
        "description": "",
        "post_count": 13,
        "id": 169072,
        "taxonomy": "post_tag",
        "tag_id": 555
     },
     "canterbury":
     {
         "name": "Canterbury",
         "slug": "canterbury",
         "parent": 0,
         "description": "",
         "post_count": 37,
         "id": 5349,
         "taxonomy": "post_tag",
         "tag_id": 777
    }
}
```

**Format for Blog Post in respect to those TAG ID**

When user click on any of those hyperlinks you'll get the TAG ID & from those TAG ID you can respective POSTS tagged with those ID. Ex- TAG ID 555 is associated with 2 POSTS.

```
{
    "555": [{
        "blog_id": 111,
        "blog_excerpt": "your blog excerpt",
        "date": "2017-04-15"
    }, {
        "blog_id": 222,
        "blog_excerpt": "your blog excerpt",
        "date": "2017-04-16"
    }],
    "777": [{
        "blog_id": 333,
        "blog_excerpt": "your blog excerpt",
        "date": "2017-04-17"
    }, {
        "blog_id": 444,
        "blog_excerpt": "your blog excerpt",
        "date": "2017-04-18"
    }]
}
```

Hope you'll get my Point.